# Return Response from Server

Tags: java, sockets, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a program to allow several Minecraft servers to communicate, but I need to have a way to return a string from a method that essentially 'waits' for a response. When a plugin attempts to retrieve what I'm calling **Server Properties**, a request is sent to the target server for that property. Since this uses a sort of event system, where another method, defined by the plugin, is run when information is received. I'll explain more in the code below.

```
public final ServerResponse retrieveProperty(String property) {
    if (!PropertyHandler.isValidProperty(property)) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return Handler.retrieveProperty(property,
                CONNECTIONS.get(entryPoint).getKey().getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When a String is received from the target server, CSC (my plugin), handles the information based on the syntax and contents, and deals with it accordingly. How would a plugin the access this information? The `ServerResponse` class is below.

```
public final class ServerResponse {

    private String plugin;
    private String identifier;

    private boolean hasResponse = false;
    private String response = null;

    protected ServerResponse(String plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.identifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "")
            .substring(0, 7);
    }

    public String getPlugin() {
        return new String(this.plugin);
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public boolean hasResponse() {
        return this.hasResponse;
    }

    protected void respond(String response) {
        this.hasResponse = true;
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }

}
```

The example I have created is shown below, but I highly doubt it is the most efficient method. Basically, how can I tell the program to wait until it has a response to return a string?

```
public String property(String property) {
    ServerResponse response = super.retrieveProperty(property);
    String aResponse = response.getResponse();
    if (!response.hasResponse()) {
        while (true) {
            if (!response.hasResponse())
                continue;
            else {
                aResponse = response.getResponse();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return aResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a design pattern called Observer, and you'll register a listener for the property change event, and when the property changes you'll fire an event for all listeners, in this lister you could have an object for Lock and you get this lock and wait for it.

Something like this:

It's just an example, doens't 'll work, you need to create your.

```
public ResponseListener implements ServerResponseListener {

    // Object use only for locking and waiting
    private Object LOCK = new Object();

    private ServerResponse serverResponse;

    // Method triggered by the observable who has its state changed and notfies its observers (this one)
    public void onChange(ServerResponse serverResponse) {
        this.serverResponse = serverResponse;

        synchronzed(LOCK) {
            // Notifies the threads waiting this object monitor
            LOCK.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    // Gets the object for locking
    public Object getLock() {
        return this.LOCK();
    }

    // Gets the response
    public ServerResponse getResponse() {
        return this.serverResponse;
    }
}

public String property(String property) {
    // Instantiate the listener
    ServerResponseListener listener = new ServerResponseListener();

    // Pass the listener as a parameter to be triggered when the response is received by the server
    ServerResponse response = super.retrieveProperty(property, listener);

    // Check if the response isn't there already
    if(listener.getResponse() == null) {
        Object lock = listener.getLock();

        // Get its monitor
        synchronzed(lock) {
            // The time is the limit for wait, use like a timeout
            try {lock.wait(1000 * 30);}catch(Excepion ex){}
        }

        ServerResponse resp = listener.getResponse();

        if(resp == null) throw new Exception("Timeout while waiting for the response");

        String aResponse = response.getResponse();

        return aResponse;
    }

    return listener.getResponse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already handled how I'm going to return the `ServerResponse`, I'm just not sure how clients could check repeatedly until something is returned. **Edit** I think I see what you mean. I'll take a better look later today.

Comment: Also, this is running on the main Server thread, and invoking `Object.wait(..)` isn't a good thing for MC servers.